# EF и превышение длины строки

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Я создал модель данных DataBase-First, при этом в базе данных есть поля на подобии varchar(150). В классе же такие поля выглядят как просто string. И при сохранении изменений cnt.SaveChanges(), если значение строки больше 150 символов, возникает исключение "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntitiyValidationErrors' property for more details". В подробностях ошибки и написано, что поле Name должно иметь тип строки или массива с максимальной длиной 150.

Можно ли узнать для текстовых полей их размер в базе данных средствами C# и обрезать строку? Или как-то "отключить" данные ошибки сохранения (чтобы EF сам обрезал строки)?

Comment: Интересно, почему Database first не [проставляет MaxLength](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.3.php) и что будет, если его проставить вручную

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдёт StringLength -- в тех случаях, когда речь идёт о пользовательском вводе в asp.net mvc приложении. Модель просто не пропустит более длинную строку.

Comment: Не знаю почему. А вручную и не хотелось бы ничего - размер поля в БД могут поменять не уведомив. А приложение у меня на WPF.

Comment: @AK судя по ошибке валидации, MaxLength как раз проставляется

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать получить параметры полей БД из метаданных:

```
public static int? GetMaxLength(this EntityObject entite, string nomPropriete)
    {
        int? result = null;
        using (XEntities contexte = XEntities.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            var queryResult = from meta in contexte.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                               .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                              from p in (meta as EntityType).Properties
                                 .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.Name == entite.GetType().Name
                                     && p.Name == nomPropriete
                                     && p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name == "String")
                              select p.TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value;
            if (queryResult.Count() > 0)
            {
                result = Convert.ToInt32(queryResult.First());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```